# Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 r2 in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: certificates, office-communicator

I am using ubuntu 13.04 64bit OS. I am new in linux.In Our network all other sysetms are windows platforms and all systems have Microsoft office communicator also.Is there any chance to use office communicator in ubuntu or any other third party software. If any software is there let me know how to install server certificate on it.(step by step)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well you can run it under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) which is a layer that allows you to run windows applications under Ubuntu.

The other option is to use Pidgin protocol plugin to connect to MS Office Communicator.  it is offered under the name pidgin-sipe.  To install, and for more information, see the SIPE Project [website](http://sipe.sourceforge.net/).

Or to install just click it [**Pidgin-Sipe** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pidgin-sipe/)